# Visual Studio Code Permanently Deletes Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Deleting a file from within Visual Studio Code permanently deletes the file, instead of sending it to the recycle bin. Why is that?

Comment: If any windows user is experiencing this yet, please notice one reason might be that you're working remotely in WSL, in that case, obviously deleted files don't go to your Windows recycle bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 0.5.0 release of VS Code files and folders deleted from the explorer will be moved to the OS trash from where you can also restore them.

Comment: I actually liked the fact that it permanently removed the file. I saw it as a design decision, thinking that when a developer chooses to delete a file, he really means "I want to erase this file"

Comment: @PixelCakeGames Sometimes you delete the wrong file!

Comment: @PixelCake you will be able to Shift-Delete to bypass trash in the same way this can be done on Windows.

Comment: @Felipe I second that motion! I've lived this way for almost 30 years and have only regretted it a few times. The Shift+Delete tip is what I came here looking for and would be great if it actually worked...this is what it gives me https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5338.png

Comment: @Kenny83: Shift + `right click` then `Delete` works too. The delete command is in that case changed to `Delete Permanently`.

Comment: @Kenny83: When you said: "The Shift+Delete tip is what I came here looking for and would be great if it actually worked", did you want to say `Shift + Delete` doesn't work? That works the same as `Shift + right click` then `Delete` and the screenshot you posted means it worked as it should. BTW, now there is a message the file can be restored with `Undo` when using delete permanently.

Comment: @Chupo_cro LOL I'm not sure, since I wrote that comment over 3 months ago and have trouble remembering what I did yesterday sometimes :P VS Code has also had many updates since then, so I can't really speak to how it was in Nov. 2020 compared to now. As such, I'll take your word for it ;-)

Comment: @Kenny83: The comment your wrote 3 months ago is not quite clear - you said the command did **not** work as it should but in the same time you uploaded the screenshot from which it could be seen the command **did** work OK :-)

Comment: It didn't work **the way I expected**...I like to *permanently* delete things with a single mouse or key press, not have to confirm, and not have a "trash can" or "recycle bin" or whatever you want to call it. But tbh, I really stopped caring about this particular issue about 5 minutes after I posted my original comment lol

Comment: This is the worse feature ARGGGGG