# How to enable Trash on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have "Files: Enable Trash" (`files.enableTrash`) enabled, as per the default. But my Linux doesn't have a Trash, so if I right-click a file in the explorer, I only see the option to "Delete Permanently".

So now I'm trying to figure out how to enable Trash with VS Code on Linux. Like perhaps I could create a `.Trash` folder somewhere where it will be picked up by VS Code, or install some Trash service.

Does VS Code support Trash on Linux, and if so, how does it detect where in the file system the Trash is located?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32078) suggests it must be possible ...

Answer (score 0):

In general, system trash bin / recycling bin support [has existed since v0.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30558679/11107541). As for Linux support, it clearly exists, since it does on my Ubuntu system (though [as I've stated before](/a/77663826/11107541), even then, it has some limitations).

Related source code can be found in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileActions.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/161d5010003b829d0d54b1c2a4c502421cc09461/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileActions.ts#L95) at the `deleteFiles` function, which notably takes a `useTrash` boolean-type parameter. In the same file, see the `moveFileToTrashHandler` and `deleteFileHandler` callback definitions. Those are respectively bound to keybindings and menu items in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileActions.contribution.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/161d5010003b829d0d54b1c2a4c502421cc09461/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileActions.contribution.ts#L64). In the keybinding and menu item for the former, note the requirement of the context key `ExplorerResourceMoveableToTrash`, and corresponding negation for the latter. The context key is controlled by code in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/views/explorerView.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/161d5010003b829d0d54b1c2a4c502421cc09461/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/views/explorerView.ts#L666)'s `onFocusChanged` function, which requires the `files.enableTrash` setting to be set to `true`, and the expression `this.fileService.hasCapability(stat.resource, FileSystemProviderCapabilities.Trash)`. For the builtin disk filesystem provider, see [src/vs/platform/files/common/diskFileSystemProviderClient.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/161d5010003b829d0d54b1c2a4c502421cc09461/src/vs/platform/files/common/diskFileSystemProviderClient.ts#L65).

> how does it detect where in the file system the Trash is located?

For the builtin disk filesystem provider, it doesn't (it being VS Code). That's electron's job. See [src/vs/platform/files/electron-main/diskFileSystemProviderServer.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/161d5010003b829d0d54b1c2a4c502421cc09461/src/vs/platform/files/electron-main/diskFileSystemProviderServer.ts#L48)'s `delete` function. It just calls `shell.trashItem`.